# How to select multiple checkboxes and fill a dropdownlist in mvc with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, drop-down-menu

I have 15 check boxes in MVC and i want to fill dropdownlist when any five of them are checked. with the help of JavaScript...please help me i am new to programming so i cant manage that to do.if you can help me with atleast javascript it is very helpful.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#timeslotee").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#Day").change(function () {
        if ($("#Country").val() != "Select") {
            var DocOptionss = {};
            DocOptionss.url = "/Sample/timeslot";
            DocOptionss.type = "POST";
            DocOptionss.data = JSON.stringify({ dayy: $("#Day").val(), docname: $("#State").val() });
            DocOptionss.datatype = "json";
            DocOptionss.contentType = "application/json";
            DocOptionss.success = function (StatesListd) {
                $("#timeslotee").empty();
                for (var i = 0; i < StatesListd.length; i++) {
                    $("#timeslotee").append("<option>" + StatesListd[i] + "</option>");
                }
                $("#timeslotee").prop("disabled", false);
            };
            DocOptionss.error = function () { alert("Error in Selecting A Day!!"); };
            $.ajax(DocOptionss);
        }
        else {
            $("#timeslotee").empty();
            $("#timeslotee").prop("disabled", true);
        }
    });
});
public JsonResult Days(string docname)
    {
        var dd = db.USERs.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Full_name == docname);
        List<string> StatesListw = new List<string>();


        if (dd.DOCTOR.DOCTOR_DAYS.Monday)
        {
            StatesListw.Add("Monday");
        }
        if (dd.DOCTOR.DOCTOR_DAYS.Tuesday)
        {
            StatesListw.Add("Tuesday");
        }
        if (dd.DOCTOR.DOCTOR_DAYS.Wednesday)
        {
            StatesListw.Add("Wednesday");
        }
        if (dd.DOCTOR.DOCTOR_DAYS.Thursday)
        {
            StatesListw.Add("Thursday");
        }
        if (dd.DOCTOR.DOCTOR_DAYS.Friday)
        {
            StatesListw.Add("Friday");
        }
        if (dd.DOCTOR.DOCTOR_DAYS.Saturday)
        {
            StatesListw.Add("Saturday");
        }
        if (dd.DOCTOR.DOCTOR_DAYS.Sunday)
        {
            StatesListw.Add("Sunday");
        }
        return Json(StatesListw);
    }
```

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific. You can't just throw fancy acronyms like MVC against a question and expect a result.

Comment: MVC in c#  and i need the code in view with javascript

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jQuery? If so, this should work:

```
var $checkboxes = $('input:checkbox');

$checkboxes.change(function(){
    var numChecked = 0;
    $checkboxes.each(function(index, element){
        if(element.checked){
            numChecked++;
        }
    });
    if(numChecked >= 5){
        //do something
    }
});
```

Comment: if i use above code sir how am i going to call a method in controller???please help me if im not disturbing you sir...

Comment: i can sir but how when i copy it here it says too long...im new to stackoverflow  help me please

Comment: you don't need to post all of your code, just the methods related to the checkboxes

Comment: i didnt write any method yet sir ..i did write write method for selecting dependable dropdownlist  i need to do it here like i did it

Comment: i will try to edit your above code as i want sir...thanks again for your consideration sir

Comment: don't post your code in the comments section, edit your original post to include your code, it shouldn't have as strict of a character limit

Comment: i add it sir please edit it for me method in my controller will "Symtons" in sample controller

Comment: and the checkboxes name will "check"

Comment: It looks like your already filling a dropdown when the #day element is changed, do you want to fill that same select box when the checkboxes are checked, or is it the same data?

Comment: i want to fill dropdownlist name with "Country" not with the same data in checkboxes .. but i can manage that if this code call to the method name "Symtons" in controller sir just edit above code to call that method...

Comment: You would need to edit the c# code to map a new url to a new method you create. Then implement my code and in the part where I say "do something" create a new ajax post which hits the new url you set up. Populate the json data in the c# method and then do the same logic you used already to create <option> tags from the response and add them to any select object using jquery

Comment: and i need to call that type of method sir ..sory i dnt kw anything else to do